# Flipping Tiles over CSS3 with Background

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to create a flip over effect where the content of the div changes, though not able to figure out why the text disappears after a few seconds.

I have added backface-visibility:hidden though no use!

**HTML**

```
<div class="tweets">
<div class="front">
    This is the front
</div>
<div class="back">
    Back this is
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tweets{
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 2s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 2s;
    transition-delay:0s;
     -webkit-transition-delay:0s;
    background:url('http://www.giantfreakinrobot.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Mad-Max.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
.tweets.flipped{
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    background:url('http://www.giantfreakinrobot.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Mad-Max.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
.back{
     transform: rotateY( 180deg );
     -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.front{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 }
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Can't see any reason for it to disappear. How and when are you adding the `flipped` class to the container? Can you post that also and maybe if possible create a demo?

Comment: You'll need to describe your expected results in more detail for us to understand what it is you are trying to achieve. If you're trying to make a flipping tile you don't operate on the tile itself, you just flip both faces. The tile acts as a container. Maybe [this example](http://codepen.io/Oka/pen/ogezPe) can help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, i have created square block of 220px(change as per your requirement), which has image you linked in question as background.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzLL45aj/)

**CSS**

```
.flip-container {
    position:relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
}
.flip-container:hover .flipper {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    filter: FlipH;
    -moz-filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter:"FlipH";
}
.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
}
.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 0.8s;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 0.8s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background:url('http://www.giantfreakinrobot.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Mad-Max.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    color:red;
}

.front:hover {
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: FlipH;
}
.front-title {
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
} 
.back-title {
font-size:25px;
text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <div class="front-title">I am front Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="back-title">I am text behind </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```